# Creating aliases beginning with + or -

Tags: linux, zsh, alias

Most of the times, I find that I'm doing:

```
% chmod +x <file> #or +r or +w
```

So, I thought about creating an alias such that:

```
% alias +x='chmod +x' # or
% alias \+x='chmod +x' # or
% alias '+x'='chmod +x'
```

but it results in:

> zsh: bad option: `-x`

Is there any other method to create the above alias? I currently am setting them up as

```
% alias c+x='chmod +x'
```

which is not what I had in mind.

Comment: have you tried escaping the + with `\+`? most special characters in filenames must be escaped. that may make your alias clumbsy to use however. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-rules-for-naming-file-and-directory-names/ this is imporant because Bash uses `+` as a reserved operator: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html Ultimately, I'm forced to conclude that using `+` in an alias is a bad choice.

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes, I did that as well. That creates `\+x` as the alias.

Comment: thats likely as close as you are going to get. the parser for BASH is going to assume that a leading + is an operator, either for math or regular expressions.

Comment: @FrankThomas I'm in zsh, if that makes any difference. I understand that `+` is an operator in shell, I was just wondering whether creating `+x` alias is allowed, since trying to execute `+x` raises a _command not found_ error.

Comment: @FrankThomas: `alias +x='chmod +x'` works fine in bash; this is a zsh problem.  @hjpotter92: This is a kludge, but if you get a "command not found" error when you type `+x`, that suggests that you may be able to create a script called `+x` in your private bin directory.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting `+` in that context has not desired effect effect because it only tells `zle` (*zsh's* command line editor) to take `+` literally. The command `alias` itself still recieves the string "+x" as first command line argument and thus tries to parse it as option.

If you pass the option `--` to the `alias` command, everything after it will be used as an argument, even if it starts with an `+` or `-`. To use your example:

```
alias -- +x='chmod +x'
alias -- -x='chmod -x'
```

---

**Note:** Many - but not all - other tools behave similarly, zsh built-ins as well as external commands. For example:

```
% touch -negative
touch: invalid option -- 'n'
Try 'touch --help' for more information.
% touch -- -negative
% ls -negative
ls: invalid option -- 'e'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
% ls -- -negative   
-negative
% rm -negative
rm: invalid option -- 'n'
Try 'rm ./-negative' to remove the file '-negative'.
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
% rm -- -negative
```

Of course, you can also do as `rm` suggests and use `./-negative` in most (all?) of these cases where paths are involved.

One notable exception is GNU `echo`. It is difficult to get it to print any options it recognizes without additional text. For example "-n":

```
% /bin/echo -n
% /bin/echo -- -n
-- -n
% /bin/echo -n -e '-n\n'
-n
```